# Understanding Joint Probability Disributions

Tags: probability, marginal-distribution

> A dice is thrown. If you get $1$, $2$ or $3$ another dice is thrown.
>   If you get any other number, the second dice is not thrown. Let $Y$ be
>   the random variable which represents a number on the second dice and
>   $X$ be the number on first dice. Find their joint distribution.

I understand that $P(X = 1,Y= 1) = \frac{1}{36}$, but will that define their joint distribution?

I understand their marginal distribution should be $P(X=x) = \frac{1}{6} x$ Belongs to $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, similarly for $Y$. But I don’t understand how one will derive this from their joint distribution?

Comment: Just compute $P(X=j, Y=k)$ for every pair $(j,k)$. Since the second dice is not rolled depending on the value of $X$, you only have to do this for $X=1,2,$ and $3$, so it’s definitely denumerable by hand.

Comment: That’d mean $1/36$ for every pair right? But than how’d I come up with their marginal distributions from that.

Comment: Got it. In the sample space of Y there 7 possible values {0,1,2,3,4,,5,6} $P(Y=0) = 0.5$. Now It makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: no not every pair. Again, what happens if we roll a $4,5,$ or $6$? Then we do not even observe $Y$ since we do not roll a second dice. So, for example, $P(X=6,Y=k)=0$ for any $k$ because its impossible to observe the event $\{X=6, Y=k\}$, right?

Comment: Yes. So I was confused how $P(Y = y) = 1/12$ $y$ belongs to {1,2,3,4,5,6} will sum to $1$ but sample space of $Y$ will also include $Y = 0$. Missed that. Thanks.